# Powershell: How to reference the nth element

Tags: html, powershell

I would like to grab the 3rd "td" element in "filterTable". How is this done in a .NET environment like Powershell ? I have tried numerous ways, like so:

```
$_.getElementsByTagName("td")[3] 
$_.getElementsByTagName("td[3]")
$_.getElementsByTagName("td:3") 
$_.getElementsByTagName("td{3}") 
$_.getElementsByTagName("td"){3}
```

However none of these seem to work. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help. Here is some context of my code:

```
$textValues = @()
$textValues = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementById("filterTable") | foreach{
    $_.getElementsByTagName("td") | foreach{
        $_ | Select InnerText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`item()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536460(v=vs.85).aspx) method on the element collection returned by `getElementsByTagName()`.

Just supply an index (zero-based):

```
$filterTable = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementById("filterTable")
$3rdTD       = $filterTable.getElementsByTagName("td").item(2)
```

---

Alternatively, use `Select-Object -Index`:

```
$filterTable.getElementsByTagName("td") |Select-Object -Index 2
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you